# Formula used to calculate the speed of a receding galaxy

Tags: astronomy, velocity, big-bang

I am trying to explain why the Hubble redshift-distance diagram can't be interpreted as evidence for a large explosion having taken place a long time ago in a static universe, sending all galaxies in motion away from us.

To do this, I want to say that in an explosion, the galaxies move away from us at a rate inversely proportional to mass. This is NOT the same as Hubble's redshift-distance diagram that shows that speeds increase with distance and do not depend on mass.

Does anyone know what formula this statement refers to? I read about it online but have not been able to match the formula to the theory.

Comment: Read online where?

Comment: Cross-posted on [astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23664/5264)

Comment: Also, that argument is not valid. Galaxies weren't formed at Big Bang and are not solid bodies of various masses. Rather they are made of individual particles (e.g. gas and stars), and formed several 100 million years after BB. An explosion from a central point could in principle launch particles at various energies and hence speeds, which could later condense to galaxies at masses independent of their velocities. I think the best argument against that scenario is given by Davis & Lineweaver (2004), summarized in [this SE answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/21340/5264).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the Big Bang. Look it up in wiki. You can also look up the Hubble redshift distance. It was determined initially by Hubble's observations of distances and redshift, and then verified with more observations. General Relativity (GR), in the standard cosmology solution for a homogeneous isotropic universe can be used to derive the formula also.

The main reason for the result is that it denotes the redshift observed from light emitted at a certain distance, and (this is the important point) where the distance is how far the universe has expanded. It's not that the galaxy or star was thrown off at a certain velocity, it's that the space itself has expanded at a velocity that is proportional to distance, and anything in it then will then have moved further away as its coordinate location moves away due to the space expansion. The matter didn't have to move, the space expanded, and that's the determining factor of the distance.

EDIT WITH ADDED PARAGRAPH, hopefully a more intuitive explanation. It does not directly have to do with the masses of the stars/galaxies which, as they would in classical physics, act as resistance to force. It is also not an explosion, we don't know what it is, and treat it as an initial condition, and a singularity, with all mass-energy and all of spacetime in an infinitesimally small region. It does not evolve according to a force from an explosion, space (and spacetime) evolves (i.e., changes) due to GR, and in cosmological solutions it's spatial slices expand. Now, it is true that in GR that expansion does have to do with the amount of mass (really mass and energy, and anything that contributes to the stress energy tensor), so that if the mass-energy density of the universe was higher it would normally slow down the expansion (I say normally because dark energy has the opposite effect). GR is a classical self consistent theory in that mass-energy creates the curvature and how it expands and accelerates (or decelerates), and that curvature determines how that same mass-energy behaves. In cosmology the initial Big Bang (read: initial condition) and the mass-energy density decides how the geometry (read: curvature) changes, and has those spatial slices expanding, with all comoving mass in it just moving with the spatial slices (i.e., at rest in them except for peculiar velocities). It is not force ---> acceleration, but rather mass-energy ----> geometry and geometry changes such as expansion ----> motion of any mass in that geometry (with any mass moving the same way per the equivalence principle, which is upheld in GR).

Since GR you may wonder what coordinate system is that all in. Well, since the universe is homogeneous and isotropic (on the average in the large), one can define a time coordinate where the spatial sections at any one time are expanding uniformly, i.e. that is a coordinate system in which the cosmic flow is observed to be uniform and isotropic. It's called a comoving frame of reference, and it can be used in GR to calculate time and distances unambiguously. It is in that frame of reference where Hubble's law holds. It is in that frame of reference where the cosmic microwave background CMB) looks homogeneous and isotropic.

The derivation of the equation is done in many places, once the solution for the GR equations are solved to the extent needed. The solution is the so-called the Friedman-Lamaitre-Robertson-Walker solution, and depends on some parameters that have been pretty well determined from astrophysical observations and the CMB, with still some remaining standard deviations.

See the Hubble law explained and derived (though it does start with the standard solution , it takes some shortcuts) at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law
For a full derivation see the Modern Cosmology textbook by Dodelson. It's an easy derivation, and the author doesn't spend much time getting the cosmology solution, but gets to it and explains things physically with enough math. There are also GR books with more formal derivations, and more physics with less astrophysics, such as Wald. The standard GR book is the now old Misner Thorne and Wheeler textbook. There's more recent books, none is perfect.

Comment: All right but the question is about  something else. At least it seems so to me

Comment: She said it has to do with mass, i.e. Resistance to force. It does not, space (and spacetime) changes due to GR, and in cosmological solutions it's spatial slices expand. Light edit in answer.

Comment: She is asking what would follow from explosion .  She is right the treatment is done (in book too) and compared to Hubble flow. If I remember mass is not necessary especially because on average galaxies are equivalent. She is aware that BB is not a big explosion into space but she want a way to show it.

Comment: See edit. Hopefully it'll help OP.